# elements of order 3 the group $R^2/Z^2$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, equivalence-relations

the group acts on addition is defined by the equivalence of all the reals that differ by squared integers.

I have $3r^2 = M^2-3n^2$ but don't know how to proceed?

Comment: I'm really very sure that this group is not what you think it is. Indeed, I'm reasonably sure it's the quotient of the plane by its integer lattice points, with the obvious coordinate-wise addition modulo 1.

Comment: oh right crap. How do I answer that?

Answer (score 0):

The comment is right. $\mathbb{R}^2 / \mathbb{Z}^2$ is the quotient of the plane by its integer lattice points. That is, we have $(x,y) \sim (u,v)$ if and only if there are $n,m \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $x - u = n$ and $y - v = m$.

Thus, an element $(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 / \mathbb{Z}^2$ has order $k$ if $kx - 0 \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $ky - 0 \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Think you can take it from there?

Comment: ok thans, it was easy i just asked the wrong question. I shall edit it when i have time